# Populate views in Android application

Tags: java, android, json

I wrote these classes and I would like to know if this is a correct way. I created a new Project with Blank activity and "Scrollable Tabs + Swipe" as Navigation type.

My main activity:

```
public class MyMainActvity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static String url = "http://www.myurl.it";

    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

        new JSONParse().execute();

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                {
                    HomeSection homeFrag= new HomeSection();
                    homeFrag.newInstance(jObj);
                    return homeFrag;
                }
            case 1:
            {
                ServiceSection servFrag= new ServiceSection();
                servFrag.newInstance(jObj);
                return servFrag;
            }
            case 2:
                {
                    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    return fragment;
                }
            case 3:
            {
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyMainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser= new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json =jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("JSONARRAY:", json.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json_data = json.getJSONObject(0);
                jObj= json_data;

                mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());

                // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
                mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
            }

            catch(JSONException exception) {

                Log.e("ERROR", exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is one of my subclassed Fragments:

```
public class HomeSection  extends Fragment {

    JSONObject _jObj;
    public HomeSection(){}

    public void newInstance(JSONObject jObj) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        _jObj= jObj;

        try{
            String content= _jObj.getString("descrizione");
            args.putString("description", content);
        }
        catch(JSONException exception){

            Log.e("ERROR JSON HOME", exception.getMessage());
        }

        // Put any other arguments
        this.setArguments(args);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        try {
            dummyTextView.setText(_jObj.getString("descrizione"));
        }
        catch(JSONException exception){

            Log.e("ERROR JSON HOME", exception.getMessage());
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

It works, but I would like if it is a correct way to populate the views in my app. Then I didn't know if in the `HomeSection` class, the Bundle that I created in the `newIstance` method is effectively necessary because I set my text in the view within the method `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too familiar with Android, so just some generic notes about the Java code:

1. Instead of using magic numbers in the switch-case use named constants. It would help maintenance a lot. There is more than one switch-case with the same 0-3 case branches. A reader might wonder: are they the same? Help them!

   Might be useful here too:

   - *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*: *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism*
   - [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)
2. ```
   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
       switch (position) {
       case 0:
           return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
       case 1:
           return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
       case 2:
           return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
       case 3:
           return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   Is it considered to be an error in the program if position is not between `0` and `3`? If it is there might be no reason to continue processing with wrong state. Consider throwing an exception or logging the error. (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)
3. Some duplication could be eliminated from the switch-case above with a helper method:

   ```
   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       switch (position) {
       case 0:
           return getUpperCaseString(R.string.title_section1);
       case 1:
           return getUpperCaseString(R.string.title_section2);
       case 2:
           return getUpperCaseString(R.string.title_section3);
       case 3:
           return getUpperCaseString(R.string.title_section4);
       }
       return null;
   }

   private CharSequence getUpperCaseString(final String input) {
       final Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
       return getString(input).toUpperCase(locale);
   }
   ```
4. `jObj` should have have a more descriptive name. What's the purpose of this field? Name it accordingly.
5. A name constant instead of `4` (`TOTAL_PAGES_COUNT`, for example) could eliminate the comment here:

   ```
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // Show 4 total pages.
       return 4;
   }
   ```
6. Field and variable naming is not consistent:

   ```
   ViewPager mViewPager;
   ...
   JSONObject _jObj;
   ...
   JSONObject json_data = json.getJSONObject(0);
   ```

   The `m` prefixes to access fields are not really necessary and it's just noise. Modern IDEs use highlighting to separate local variables from fields.

   Field names should not start with underscore. See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions* and [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, 6.1 Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/):

   > Names of fields that are not final should be in mixed 
   >   case with a lowercase first letter and the first letters of 
   >   subsequent words capitalized.